# Add the permissions to the Group - Django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I am writing a REST API to create Group and assign permissions to that group.

**Issue:**
How to create POST Method so that I can create a group having those permissions.

[image]

Here is Snippet of code so far I have came

**Groupserializer**

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
class Meta:
    model = Group
    fields = ('name','permissions')
```

**Views**

```
class UsersGroupCreateView(APIView):
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

def post(self , request , *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = GroupSerializer(data = request.data)
    
    if serializer.is_valid():
        data = serializer.validated_data
        group = Group.objects.create(name = data.get('name'), permissions = 
                                     data.get('permissions'))
    
        return Response({"status":"Group Created"},status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

class GetPerm(APIView):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    permissions = serializers.serialize('json', Permission.objects.all())
    return Response(permissions)
```

**permissions from GetPerm() has following data:**

"[{"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "Can add log entry", "content_type": 1, "codename": "add_logentry"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 2, "fields": {"name": "Can change log entry", "content_type": 1, "codename": "change_logentry"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 3, "fields": {"name": "Can delete log entry", "content_type": 1, "codename": "delete_logentry"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 4, "fields": {"name": "Can view log entry", "content_type": 1, "codename": "view_logentry"}}]"

**Sorry , if I am not being much clear**
**Any help would be appreciated !!**

Comment: Exactly what issue you are facing?

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope you will get clue. Sorry  @JPG if I am not being specific.

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, you cannot directly assign `ManyToMany` relationships when first creating the object. You need to do it manually *after* :

```
 # ...
    if serializer.is_valid():
        data = serializer.validated_data

        group = Group.objects.create(name = data.get('name'))
        [group.permissions.add(p) for p in data.get('permissions')]
    
        return Response({"status":"Group Created"},status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and it's something like this.

```
        group = Group.objects.create(name = data.get('name'))
        try:
            permissions = request.data.get('permissions')
            for permission_index in permissions:
                permission=Permission.objects.get(id=permission_index)
                group.permissions.add(permission)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in creating")
        return Response({"status":"Group Created"},status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

also thanks to @afonso.